# How to receive correct class loader for jar in web application?

Tags: java, resources, web, classloader

I have application mywebapp. This application depends from myjarconfig.jar.
File myjarconfig.jar contains file config.xml.
To take resource I use code:

```
InputStream confStream = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/conf/config.xml");
```

But I always receive null. When I look in debugger - I see that ClassLoader is mywebapp. Why it is not jar file? What need to check?
Thanks.

Comment: how is myjarconfig.jar added to the classpath? the webapp classloader should find it if it's in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Yes, it is present in WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your jar is somewhere in WEB-INF/lib, container's classpath, bootstrap classpath, etc. then you should use

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/conf/config.xml")
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have checked in debugger about ContextClassLoader - it has canonical path ...apache-tomcat\\work\\Catalina\\localhost\\mywebapp\\loader\\. Seems that tomcat use some cache. Does it possible work with classloader in this case?

Comment: Or may be this because I use embedded tomcat of eclipse?

Comment: What is the place you try to load the "/conf/config.xml"? Is it servlet or something else? Could you show the source code?